# remove tab from pab panel in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

When I use remove method in tabpanel:

```
this.tabPanel.remove(tab);
```

It set setActive tab in last. I would like to set on previous. Now can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the event [beforeremove](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-event-beforeremove) to get the index of the removed tab and set the previous one.

```
var tabs = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    items: [{
        title: 'Tab 1',
        html: 'A simple tab',
        closable: true
    }, {
        title: 'Tab 2',
        closable: true,
        html: 'Another one'
    }, {
        title: 'Tab 3',
        closable: true,
        html: 'Another one'
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

tabs.on('beforeremove', function(tabs, tab) {
        var idx = tabs.items.indexOf(tab) - 1;
        setTimeout(function() {
            tabs.setActiveTab(idx);
        }, 350);

});
```

You can check the [working example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/rs).